# Mysql stored procedure speed up

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to find a pair from a given table which has around 1,50,000 entries, I wrote a stored procedure which picks up one entry and then traverses remaining 1,49,999  entry in the table and finds pair and i'm continuing for the remaining numbers as such and I also use linear search concept of not traversing backwards.It takes me 2hrs and 5 mins for the whole table to get complete. How do I speed up the process?
They say declaring variables as local can speed up the process
eg declare first_carat double;
declare first_measure_height double;
But tis also doesnt speed up and I also considered to set autocommit=0 and came to know that mysql doesnt allow this explicit declaring. Any valid suggestions for speeding up? 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Post your code, table structure, sample data, desired result. Otherwise it's hard (or even impossible) to answer. And stop following blindly suggestions what to do, when given they have the same information we do have now, this clearly can't be answered. Autocommit has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Do you use clustered or nonclustered indexes? Can you post your table structure and example sql?